# Trying to find and kill a process by PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, process, arguments, kill-process

I have the following script to find the process "dotnet.exe". In my system, I have many dotnet.exe processes running. But I want to kill the "dotnet.exe" which has command line argument  "MyService\Web\argument". I'm trying to do it by the following script. But it doesn't find anything, although I see the process in the Task Manager.

```
$process = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | select name, commandline

foreach ($p in $process)
{
    if ($p.name -contains "dotnet.exe" -and $p.commandline -contains "web")
    {
        $kp =    Get-Process $p;
        $kp.CloseMainWindow();
        if (!$kp.HasExited)
        {
            $kp | Stop-Process -Force
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host name: $p.name and param: $p.commandline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does $process contain the one that you are looking for?

Comment: `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like '%dotnet.exe%' and commandline like '%web%'").Terminate()`?

Comment: You're using the wrong comparison operator.  `-contains` is designed for array comparisons against a single element.  Use `-like`

Comment: I get error as: Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a method named 'Terminate'.
At C:\practice\kill_web.ps1:6 char:8
+        $p.Terminate()
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Terminate:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Apparently you tried to retrofit the code I posted into the code in your question. Why did you do that? Please do not get creative *before* you got things working. Use the code I posted as-is without any modifications or additions.

Comment: Yes, u are right. I missed the warping the statement with (). It is working perfectly .

Comment: Would you mind to give your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is filter the process list directly via `Get-WmiObject` and then terminate the matching process(es):

```
$fltr = "name like '%dotnet.exe%' and commandline like '%web%'"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter $fltr | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Terminate()
}
```

You could also call `Terminate()` directly on the output of `Get-WmiObject` like this:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter $fltr).Terminate()
```

However, there are situations where this could fail, e.g. if `Get-WmiObject` doesn't return any results, or if you're using PowerShell v2 or earlier and `Get-WmiObject` returns more than one result (passing a method call to the members of an array requires member enumeration, which was introduced with PowerShell v3). Using a `ForEach-Object` loop is both more robust and backwards-compatible.

Comment: In case, (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter $fltr) return null, the call Terminate() would result in error. So I would suggest having a null check condition.

Comment: @masiboo Please read again. I already addressed this issue in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about single line statement. (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter $fltr).Terminate()

Comment: Please. Read. Again. The paragraph right below that code snippet details the caveat.

Answer (score 1):

The `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet returns quite useful objects, but you have stripped off everything by selecting only the **Name** and **CommandLine** parameters:

```
$process = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | select name, commandline
```

If you remove the `| select name, commandline` part, you can still loop through each process but also make use of methods like `Terminate()` that will still be available.

You could do it in one shot, as per @ansgar-wiechers comment, or still make use of the loop and add in more logging, etc. if you wanted:

```
$process = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process

foreach($p in $process){
    if($p.Name -eq "*dotnet.exe" -and $p.CommandLine -like "*web*"){
       $p.Terminate()
       # and so on... 
    }
}
```

Note also the comment from @TheIncorrigible1 about the use of comparison operators. I have used `-eq` for the process name and `-like` for the command line.

Comment: I think in your code, u mentioned $p.Name -and $p.Name. It must be $p.commandline. Anyway, I get error like Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a method named 'Terminate'.
At C:\practice\kill_web.ps1:6 char:8
+        $p.Terminate()
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Terminate:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: I have fixed the typo with the property name.

Comment: Make sure you are using the actual object returned by `Get-WmiObject`. You must **not** use the `select` statement, as this will make methods such as `Terminate()` unavailable. I have updated my answer to make this more explicit.